# Executing cardano-cli inside a docker container from another docker container

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, docker

Can anyone help me with something, I'm trying to run a web server over the cardano-node docker image.

I have some solutions in mind but I would like to have some feedback from you.

Approach # 1

Build a new image over the cardano-node docker image that install node and runs my server code.

My questions around this are:

- Where can I find the cardano-node Dockerfile? I need to know what is already setup and what is the underlaying Linux distro.
- Related to the previous one, how can I install Node over the cardano-node image? I have tried multiple mechanisms like apt-get and nothing works.

Approach # 2

Create my webserver in a different docker image and make the container communicate with the cardano-node container.

Questions:

- How can I communicate my web server container with the cardano-node container so I can run the cardano-cli commands?

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1 is the only one that makes sense to me in my limited knowledge of Containers. Containers, I understand, are different operating system context, not just different process so there isn't really IPC outside of the Docker api. The TCP/IP stack really shines here. Have a small web service with your Cardano-node / Cardano-cli which does basic things with the software and have an additional webserver act as the application level service, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, that's something that I've thought about. However, the way the official Docker image was built makes it hard to extend. I have been thinking of creating my own following the Linux setup steps from the docs.

The other part of your answer is that the docker-node image exposes the IPC through a volume, so that makes me think that it is possible to achieve such inter container communication; I don't know-how.

This is my docker-compose.yml

Comment: ```yml
version: '3.1'

services:
  cardano-node:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-node
    environment:
      - NETWORK=testnet
      - CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket
    volumes:
      - data:/data
      - node-ipc:/ipc
      - ./dist/apps/cardano-server/outputs:/outputs

volumes:
  data:
  node-ipc:
```

Answer (score 1):

NIX is used to build the image. There is no Dockerfile (as far as I know).
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/nix/docker/default.nix

---

You can establish cross-container communication via node.socket:

```
docker run -e NETWORK=mainnet -v node-ipc:/ipc inputoutput/cardano-node
docker run -e NETWORK=mainnet -v node-ipc:/ipc inputoutput/some-node-client
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/cardano-node

Comment: Thanks, I might try that later. For now, I'm building upon a community image for the Cardano Node.